# How to construct a RV with a given conditional distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\Sigma$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$. I would like to know if it is possible to construct a $Y$ such that $P(Y \in \cdot| \Sigma)$ is a pre-specified distribution.

I've seen many setups like:

- Flip a coin, if heads roll a 10 sided die, if tails roll a 6 sided die
- Pick a uniform $\mu \in [-1,1]$, then let $X$ be a Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$
- Let $\Phi$ be a Poisson point process, choose $Y_k$ conditionally independent on $\Phi$ where $Y_k$ has an $N(X_k,1)$ distribution, where $X_k$ is the $k$th atom of $\Phi$.

I wonder what the underlying probabilistic structure needed to create such setups is. Is it always possible to expand the probability space to accomodate specified conditional distributions?

Comment: If you remember that to construct a random variable Y with prescribed distribution one can choose Y=G(U), where U is uniform on (0,1), for some suitable function G, then you might think that, if Σ is the σ-algebra generated by some random variable Z, then Y=G(Z,U) for some U independent of Z and uniform on (0,1) and some suitable function G, does the job. And you would be right to think so...